# How to assert integer and float type values are within the bound

Tags: groovy, soapui

```
else if(KeyName=="amount")
    {
        log.info ("Result:" +actualvalue)
        assert actualvalue >=  lowerbound && actualvalue <=  upperbound
    }
```

> Result: 1009.750000

*lowerbound is taken 0 and upperbound = 10010.*

I am printing all the values and given below.

```
actualvalue; Sun Jul 02 07:19:36 IST 2017:INFO:1009.75000***0***10010
```

But condition is failing.
How to compare these two values?
Is it because of type mismatch?
How to resolve this?

Comment: ChangGan, have you got chance to try? doe the below solution helps?

Comment: It worked for me when type is changed toFloat()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def lBound = 0
def uBound = 10010
def actualValue = 1009.750000
assert lBound <= actualValue, 'actual value is less than lower bound'
assert uBound >= actualValue, 'actual value is greater than upper bound'
```

Not sure how you declared. Even the below code snippet works.

```
int lBound = 0
int uBound = 10010
float actualValue = 1009.750000
assert lBound <= actualValue && uBound >= actualValue
```